# Select columns which are different between 2 table versions

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say I have the following table structure:

```
Table1

        FixedColumn1 FixedColumn2 ChangingColumn1 ChangingColumn2
        Test1        Test11       1               3
        Test2        Test22       2               5
```

Same `Table1` updated and saved in another table with the same structure

```
SameTable1Updated

        FixedColumn1 FixedColumn2 ChangingColumn1 ChangingColumn2
        Test1        Test11       77               23
        Test2        Test22       22               5
        Test3        Test33       5                null
```

Now, I have the following table in which I want to save the modified data:

```
DifferencesTable

FixedColumn1 FixedColumn2 Change         ColumnName       NewValue OldValue
Test1        Test11       Modified        ChangingColumn1  77       1
Test1        Test11       Modified        ChangingColumn2  23       3
Test2        Test22       Modified        ChangingColumn1  22       2
Test3        Test33       Added           ChangingColumn1   5       null
```

The combination of `FixedColumn1` and `FixedColumn2` is `unique(like a primary key).`

I have an idea on how to do this in code working with `DataTables`, but is it possible in `sql`?

Edit:

So basically Table1 will be updated at some point and saved in SameTable1Updated (some rows will change, some will be completely removed or some will be added). If row values have changed from Table1 and still appear in SameTable1Updated, they will be added with the parameter `Change` as `Modified` and with the `OldValue` from Table`and with the new value from`SameTable1Updated`. If the row will be completely removed from Table1, it will appear with the parameter`Change`as`Removed`and with`OldValue`parameter as the values from`Table1`and`NewValue` parameter as null for all records. 
And the other way around for newly added rows in Table2.

I've explained the situation in the best way that I can. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: i have an idea for this but its not clear in my head. which table has new values? first or second? in your expected output your new values `77` and `3` are coming from both tables. can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: please describe your query building logic (DifferencesTable logic)

Comment: @Badiparmagi, @Vecchiasignora I've updated the question with more details and a different `DifferencesTable` structure so I can explain my logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the tables to find ChangingColumn1 changes. Do the same for ChangingColumn2 changes. `UNION ALL` the results:

```
select t1.FixedColumn1, t1.FixedColumn2,
       stu.ChangingColumn1 as NewValue, t1.ChangingColumn1 as OldValue
from Table1 t1
join SameTable1Updated stu
    on  t1.FixedColumn1 = stu.FixedColumn1
    and t1.FixedColumn2 = stu.FixedColumn2
    and t1.ChangingColumn1 <> stu.ChangingColumn1
UNION ALL
select t1.FixedColumn1, t1.FixedColumn2,
       stu.ChangingColumn2 as NewValue, t1.ChangingColumn2 as OldValue
from Table1 t1
join SameTable1Updated stu
    on  t1.FixedColumn1 = stu.FixedColumn1
    and t1.FixedColumn2 = stu.FixedColumn2
    and t1.ChangingColumn2 <> stu.ChangingColumn2
order by t1.FixedColumn1, t1.FixedColumn2
```

Comment: I've updated the question with a different structure. Thank you for answering. I will try to test your answer and try to update it to my structure accordingly.

Comment: What about deleted rows?

Comment: I have explained it in the edit the best way I could. If it is still unclear I can try again. They will appear in the Differences table with the column `OldValue` value with their value, and the column `NewValue` as null and the `Change` column value as 'Removed'.

Comment: Your answer is the best I could find. Thank you.